# MySQL Select rows that match multiple rows in related table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

The following tables are much larger, but have been downsized for ease of the question

**Table 1 - exercise_rolladex**

```
Exercise_ID | Exercise_Name
---------------------------
1            Pushups
2            Turkish Get Ups
3            Squats
4            Ice Skater
```

**Table 2 - exercise_planes**

```
Exercise_Plane_ID | Exercise_Plane
----------------------------------
1                  Sagittal
2                  Frontal
3                  Transverse
```

**Table 3 - exercise_has_planes**

```
Exercise_ID | Exercise_Plane_ID
-------------------------------
1             1
2             1
2             2
2             3
3             1
4             2
4             3
```

My question is: How can I structure a Query where I can find the Exercise_ID of each exercise which has Exercise_Plane_ID=1 AND Exercise_Plane_ID=2. In other words, find the exercises that have both Sagittal AND Frontal planes of motion.

The Correct Query

```
   SELECT e.Exercise_Name, p.Exercise_Plane 
   FROM exercise_rolladex e
   INNER JOIN exercise_has_planes h ON h.Exercise_ID=e.Exercise_ID
   INNER JOIN exercise_planes p ON p.Exercise_Plane_ID=h.Exercise_Plane_ID
   WHERE p.Exercise_Plane_ID IN(2,1)
   GROUP BY e.Exercise_ID
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT h.Exercise_Plane_ID ) >= 2
```

**UPDATE FOLLOW UP QUESTION**
How then would I include an exclusion? for example, find the exercises with plane_id 2 and 3, but exclude exercises with plane_id 1 (The correct result being "Ice Skater")

I went ahead and answered my own question:

```
   SELECT e.Exercise_Name, p.Exercise_Plane 
   FROM exercise_rolladex e
   INNER JOIN exercise_has_planes h ON h.Exercise_ID=e.Exercise_ID
   INNER JOIN exercise_planes p ON p.Exercise_Plane_ID=h.Exercise_Plane_ID
   WHERE p.Exercise_Plane_ID IN(2,3)
       AND e.Exercise_ID NOT IN
       (SELECT Exercise_ID FROM exercise_has_planes WHERE Exercise_Plane_ID='1')
   GROUP BY e.Exercise_ID
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT h.Exercise_Plane_ID ) >= 2
```

Thanks to Mr. Brownstones answer from a different question.
[SQL query to exclude items on the basis of one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426128/sql-query-to-exclude-items-on-the-basis-of-one-value)

Comment: +1 excellent post.  If I wanted to hit the db with a series of 'where p.Exercise_ID In (2,3)' inquiries ... would that be repetitive calls or is there such a mysql query that could bring back an array of arrays given an input like 'where p.Exercise_ID IN (array(2,3),array(3,4),array(5,6)) ?  Seems like a php loop should be hitting the db, but I had to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this,this will check the plan id with your given input ids and filter out there count in each exercise group if count returns more than one then it means exercise has planes,having clause will fulfill the scenario of having both planes in exercise

```
SELECT e.Exercise_Name, 
p.Exercise_Plane 
FROM exercise_rolladex e
INNER JOIN exercise_has_planes h ON h.Exercise_ID=e.Exercise_ID
INNER JOIN exercise_planes p ON p.Exercise_Plane_ID=h.Exercise_Plane_ID
WHERE p.Exercise_Plane_ID IN(2,1)
GROUP BY e.Exercise_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT h.Exercise_Plane_ID ) >= 2
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dad0a/3)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid - Thanks for the answer. works well. I updated my post with a follow up question involving exclusion if you want to take a crack at it.

Comment: @The4thIceman you are most welcome and i gave you an upvote for the effort of your own follow answer keep it up